# Ubuntu - Terminal error set: variable name when opening

Tags: gnome-terminal, settings

I'm not so familiar with ubuntu but when I start gnome-terminal i got this error:

```
set: Variable name must begin with a letter
```

It also doesn't recognise any command. Have you got any idea of how to solve it? thank you!

Comment: Have you set your login shell to `csh` (or `tcsh`), or modified your gnome-terminal preferences to run a C-shell?

Comment: No I didn't, I think I could have removed some file accidentally when I removed matlab.

Comment: Aside from not recognizing any command, does the terminal work? does it show a prompt? what happens if you type `/bin/bash`?

Comment: It works saying that it cannot localize lesspipe beacuse /usr/bin:/bin is not included in PATH, the same for the command dircolors and ls

Comment: What are the outputs of `echo $PATH` and `/bin/cat /etc/environment`?

Comment: forst = `/home/federica/bin `. `/bin/cat` block the terminal. and `/etc/environment` says permisison denied

Comment: Please run `/bin/cat /etc/environment` as a whole command (not two separate commands)

Comment: Ok thank you! the output is `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`

Comment: OK let's try `/bin/cp ~/.profile ~/.profile.old ; /bin/cp /etc/skel/.profile ~/.profile` and then `/usr/bin/chsh -s /bin/bash`. Then try opening a new terminal.

Comment: Got the same error, I notice that I don't have ~/.bash_profile and ~./bash_login

Comment: Next try `/bin/cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.old ; /bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc`. Then try opening a new terminal.

Comment: Same, I noticed also that in the terminal doesn't appear the hostnam,e, it appears after i digit `/bin/bash` and `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin`
 At that point everything works, but when I open a new terminal everything comes back to the start

Comment: Please check under the terminal's `Edit` --> `Profile preferences` --> `Command` dialog that you don't have the `Run a custom command instead of my shell` option checked

Comment: No it isn't checked

Comment: apparently i resolved by adding the Path I said before in .bashrc file. Thank you very much for your time and for your help!

Comment: Apologies - I should have said to **log out and back in** after copy the new `~/.profile` (simpy starting a fresh terminal isn't enough - the profile isn't sourced for interactive, non-login shells)